# Google Analytics Custom Filter Not Reporting Correctly

Tags: google-analytics

I have created a Google Analytics profile for one of my domains to filter my reporting for a single URL string parameter: "id=21", but I am still receiving unwanted ids such as "id=19" and "id=30". How do I get ensure only "id=21" is the only one showing? I am fairly new to this process, so please go easy on me.

My analytics configuration:

Filter Type: 
- Custom Filter
- Include
- Filter Field: Request URI
- Filter Pattern: id=21
- Case Sensitive: No

Thanks!
Matt

Comment: UPDATE - I believe these reported URLs may have been from a previous filter on the same profile though I am not sure why they wouldn't have disappeared with the filter update.

Comment: Filters aren't retroactive. Is the data looking ok since you applied this new filter?

Answer (score 0):

You've set up the include filter, but you don't have any exclude ones. Have a look at [this video](http://services.google.com/analytics/breeze/en/filters/index.html), there's a thorough explanation.

Comment: "this video" is 404